# How to make program wait for a delivery status of the mail using Java mail API

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am implementing a program which has to send mails to users, one after the other. But the problem is it has to wait until it gets the the delivery status for the previously sent mail. So how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you check out the [DeliveryStatus Class](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/dsn/DeliveryStatus.html)? It's part of the JavaMain API and should return the status to you. Once you receive the status, you can then send the next piece of mail.

Answer (score 0):

You will **significantly** slow down your mail sending process by doing this.  The deliery status is a message that's sent back to your mailbox.  You'll need to poll your mailbox until a new message arrives and correlate the new message with the message you sent.  Plus, and this is the most important part, there's no guarantee you'll **ever** get a delivery status for a particular message.  It's up to the mail server on the remote end whether it sends a delivery status, and if so whether it sends it in a format you can recognize.